# Como consumir menos memória em runtime C#?

Tags: c#, .net, gerenciamento-de-memória, runtime

O que eu gostava de saber é quais são as formas mais eficientes para consumir menos memória em *runtime*.

Uso de variáveis **"static"** ?

Criar objeto com instancias ou uma `static class`?

Uso do `Dispose()` para libertar memória, etc.

Comment: Apenas tentando adivinhar, suspeito que está a corrigir o problema errado. A maior parte das aplicações não tem problemas de memoria a menos que façam coisas que não devam.

Comment: Na verdade, só queria dicas de como programar de forma mais eficiente no que diz respeito ao uso de de variáveis e metodos

Comment: O `Dispose` não libera memória, pelo menos não deveria, porque vai depender de quem o implementou. O `Dispose` deve servir para liberação de recursos externos e apenas isso. Sobre o _static_, realmente pode haver um ganho em alguns casos porque não há passagem de referência do `this` para o método, mas você precisa considerar que, se está tão preocupado com esse tipo de coisa, deveria estar usando uma linguagem mais apropriada para o problema que está tendo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A pergunta começa um pouco ampla. Há muitas maneiras e o assunto me interessa, acho legal usar técnicas de economia de memória porque elas ajudam muito na performance. Menos memória usada (no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)) traz menos lixo gerado, menos coletas, menos pausas, menos *overhead* pra gerenciamento da memória.

Uso de variáveis estáticas tendem a gastar mais memória, ou pelo menos retê-la por mais tempo. Se a semântica que precisa é essa, ok usar, caso contrário não use.

Porém o seu uso pode ser muito útil, não para economizar, mas sim para evitar coletas desnecessárias. Se você sabe que não haverá acesso concorrente (em alguns casos é possível, só é preciso mais cuidado) e que o objeto muda algumas vezes, mas sempre mantém uma instância dele, pode ser mais interessante criar um objeto e reusá-lo, pode ser uma forma "de pobre" de fazer um *pool* de objetos. Mas é preciso entender o que está fazendo. Feito corretamente cria-se menos objetos e gera menos coletas dando menos pausas. Uma das dificuldades é quando o objeto não tem tamanho definido, como o caso de *strings*, outra é que pode perder localidade e o objeto ficar longe do seu *container*, oque pode fazer tudo ficar mais lento, aí começa criar o problema que linguagens que não possuem GC têm (ao contrário da crença popular, GC pode oferecer melhor performance em muitos cenários).

Não importa se a classe é estática ou não. Ela em si não define estado, a única coisa é que não pode ter estado em uma instância dela, mas pode ter instâncias de outros objetos dentro dela.

O `Dispose()` é interessante onde ele é necessário, e tem várias [perguntas sobre isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dispose?sort=votes&pageSize=50) (acho que existe mais sem a *tag*).

[*Pool* de objetos é uma dica forte e .NET mais recente (2.1) já tem isto](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/docs/specs/memory.md) mais ou menos pronto para as situações triviais. E tem adicionais como o [*pool* de *streams*](https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream), só pra ficar em um exemplo.

O uso do [`ref` em `structs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) pode trazer um ganho enorme, mas novamente, precisa saber usar certo. Veja também [Para que serve esse 'in' em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309784/101).

As técnicas são muitas. Tem coisas mais específicas, tem coisas que dependem do que está fazendo, tem muitas coisas que são pequenos detalhes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -2):

Usar Static é a pior coisa que podes fazer em termos de memória. Ao usar Static estás a dizer ao servidor que esta variável está sempre disponível na memória pois é inicializada assim que o programa inicia.

O que é que recomendo?

Não cries variáveis para guardar valores que só vão ser utilizados uma vez.
Exemplo:

```
int result = num1 + num2;
if(result<0)
{}
```

Pode ser resumido em

```
if((num1+num2)<0) {}
```

Outra coisa que recomendo é utilizar o using () para que todas as variáveis utilizadas dentro desse bloco sejam recolhidas pelo garbage collector assim que o código sair desse bloco.

Comment: O último parágrafo não faz o menor sentido. O uso de `Dispose` não deve ter absolutamente nada a ver com coleta de lixo, ele deve ser usado para liberação de recursos externos. Se alguém implementa `Dispose` forçando a coleta, está fazendo isso completamente errado. Inclusive, forçar a coleta de lixo é uma das piores coisas que se pode fazer quando se quer cuidar da memória.

Comment: Usar `static` está longe de ser a pior coisa que pode fazer com memória, na verdade há casos que é a melhor. Servidor?!? Seu exemplo economiza zero em memória. Acho que não entendeu a funcionalidade do `using` e vide também comentário do @LINQ.