# O que é referência de tipos?

Tags: c#, tipagem, referência

Estava [lendo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) a respeito da palavra chave `ref` e me deparei com um aviso que dizia para não confundir *passagem por referência* com *referência de tipos*. Sem dúvidas que este aviso me deixou confuso e despertou mais dúvidas a respeito do assunto, pois não consegui visualizar a explicação.

## Pergunta

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber o que é referência de tipos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tradução ruim (acredito eu). Está falando de **tipos por referência**. Eu falo sobre isso em [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101).

São tipos que naturalmente já são objetos apontados em algum lugar e isso tem implicações de como se usa e como se comporta. Falei disto em [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

Esse recurso `ref` não é novo, já existia desde o C# 1.0. Ele permitia passar tipos por referência, ou seja, você criava um alias para o dado, então tinha uma variável no método (era sempre um parâmetro) que apontava para um dado em outro lugar, e o C# garante que isto seria sempre local (no *stack*).

O que tem de novo é que esse `ref` agora pode ser em uma variável local que não seja um parâmetro, pode ser um retorno e é possível até criar um tipo por valor que seja por referência. Confuso?

Na verdade usando um `ref struct` está criando um tipo por referência, não há dúvida disso. Então os *links* falam de algo ligeiramente obsoletos. A diferença é que este é um tipo por referência alocado na *stack*, antes todos os tipos por referência eram alocados no *heap*. Isso reduz muito a pressão no *garbage collector*. Muitos tipos não trabalham com objetos com tempo de vida que exijam o *heap*, mas precisam ter uma semântica de [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) e era um problema as duas coisas estarem atreladas. Esse novo recursos permite o tempo de vida curto, local, gerenciado automaticamente e manter o acesso indireto ao dado, como se fosse uma classe.

É um enorme ganho de eficiência em vários cenários. Mas sei que será pouco utilizado, porque a maioria dos programadores só se preocupam em funcionar e ser fácil pra eles. Tenho tido contato com programadores experientes que não se preocupam com essas coisas. Acredite, algumas pessoas relativamente novatas que aqui convivem já estão fazendo coisas melhores que experientes que acham que nada dessas coisas tem valor.

Existe o engenheiro e o curioso experiente.

Falei sobre o assunto em [Para que serve esse 'in' em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309784/101). Quando junta isso com a [imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) dá um poder bem interessante.

Exemplo:

```
public readonly ref struct RefRoPoint4D {
    public readonly double X;
    public readonly double Y;
    public readonly double Z;
    public readonly double W;
    public RefRoPoint4D(double x, double y, double z, double w) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
        W = w;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Struct/RefExample.cs).

Sempre que usar isso você terá um ponteiro na variável que apontará para o objeto real. Ele não pode ser usado em nada que vá ao *heap* que tem tempo de vida maior que o dele.

Comment: No caso da estrutura `RefRoPoint4D` o propósito seria passar ela para um método sem a intenção de modificação, certo?

Comment: Sem modificar em qualquer situação, que é algo que toda `struct` deveria ser.