# Instanciação de DateTime na memória

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, objetos, memória

Estou estudando sobre C# e me surgiu uma dúvida: Vi que o `DateTime` é um tipo valor (`struct`) e não referência, certo?

O que me deixa dúvidas é que, na minha cabeça, os tipos referências necessitam de instanciação utilizando o `New` (para ser criado no *heap*).

Exemplo:

`Produto nome1 = new Produto`, e assim o `nome1` faz referência (apontando como uma seta) ao produto criado.

Mas porque fazemos `DateTime nome2 = new DateTime();` se ele é um tipo valor e não referência (logo não vai apontar para nada no *heap*)?

Na minha cabeça sempre que utilizo o `new` é para instanciar, e minha mente elabora um desenho onde determinada coisa aponta para outra como referência criada no *heap*.

[image: diagrama de alocação]

[image: diagrama de referência]

Comment: Tem uma resposta muito boa do Jon Skeet sobre isso se não houverem objeções posso a traduzir: https://stackoverflow.com/a/204009/11379709

Comment: @AugustoVasques que já está ligeiramente defasada, as coisas evoluem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todos objetos precisam ser [instanciados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182990/101), não só os tipos por referência.

Na verdade os tipos por referência existem além do que imagina. Esqueça tudo o que já viu antes em documentações e informações antigas sobre essas duas formas de tipos em C#. As versões mais novas tem meio termo. [Tem `struct` por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318525/101) que nunca está no *heap*. Tem material que ensinou várias coisas erradas há 20 anos atrás.

De fato o `new` pode parecer estranho, ainda mais se vier de uma linguagem que usa essa palavra, até como operador, para indicar uma alocação de memória no *heap*. Mas entenda que em C# ela é usada para indicar que vai chamar um construtor ali na frente, já que a sintaxe do construtor é igual a da função, e é interessante mostrar explicitamente que está chamando um construtor.

O que é uma pena já que assim não pode identificar alocação no *heap*, que é ineficiente, porque o `new` não é exclusivo para este caso, e sim para qualquer chamada de construtor, que faz instanciação de objeto. Tem outras formas de instanciar um objeto mesmo diretamente, através de literais (não existe para `DateTime`.

O `new` nada tem a ver com tipos por referência ou alocação no *heap*, é sobre chamada de construtor, tire o erro da mente e comece usar o a conceituação correta. Existe questões técnicas mais internas mas não precisa saber delas para usar e entender corretamente.

> na minha cabeça

não funciona, tem que apender o que realmente é, o que está fazendo perguntando aqui, parabéns.

Inclusive pode fazer isto e poucas pessoas sabem:

```
DateTime data = new();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/New.cs).

Também desconhecem o [`DateOnly()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e [`TimeOnly()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Veja mais:

- [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101)
- [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101)
- [Para que serve esse 'in' em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309784/101)
- [Quando usar record ou class no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/481890/101)

E siga os *links* contidos nelas.